# How to get Application Layer Packets from a URL using Windows Filtering Platform

Tags: wfp

I want to block a set of URLs using **Windows Filtering Platform**. I need to get the Application Layer Packets only in order to accomplish that.. Is there anyway to get the Application Level Packets?

Answer (score 3):

You can use WinDivert which is a WFP callout driver in kernel mode and it is user mode library. It is an open source project under (LGPL) license 
[check out it is documentation](http://reqrypt.org/windivert-doc.html#filter_usage)

Comment: the documentation url seems broken. Is the content still available?